# How can I place a pdf asset into a empty PDF page?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfbox, pypdf

I have multiple PDF files with small sizes (e.g. 3cm x 2 cm) exported from Adobe Indesign.
I want to compose many of these into one new PDF which has the size of a whole page.
The small PDFs contain a plotter line in a special color which would get lost if I convert them into images.

How can I place these PDFs (at given positions) using python and without losing the special color.

I tried to read into pypdf, pypdf2 and reportlab but I got lost and the examples I found did not work. I do not need the full code, a hint into the right direction would be enough (even with another language if necessary).

Thanks

Comment: Do you have InDesign at the hand? It sounds like a rather common task for Extendscript. Depends on details of course, especially that 'special color'. It wouldn't hurt if you upload a couple of the pdf's somewhere to test the possible solutions.

Comment: And on Windows you can run InDesign and call its API with Python, if you want to use Python in your workflow.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But the goal is to automate this on a server where I will not have access to InDesign.

Comment: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/add-watermark.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from joining / merging pages from different documents into one output PDF, PyMuPDF lets you also embed pages from PDFs **into an existing page** of some target PDF (as if it were an image).

You can select a subrectangle within the source page (a "clip") and the target rectangle of the target page. Multiple embedded source pages in the same target page are also supported.

This embedding maintains all original source page features - it will **not be converted** to an image.

Scaling between source / target rectangles will be done as necessary.

This snippet will take the full page number 0 of a source PDF and place it inside a rectangle of a page in the target PDF.

The source page will be positioned centered in the target rectangle.

```py
import fitz  # import PyMuPDF
source = fitz.open("source.pdf")  # source PDF
target = fitz.open("target.pdf")  # target PDF
target_page = target[pagenumber]  # desired page in target

# if you want a new page, create it like so:
# target_page = target.new_page()

target_rect = fitz.Rect(100, 100, 300, 250)  # show source page here

# if you want to cover the full target page, use
# target_rect = target_page.rect

target_page.show_pdf_page(target_rect,
    source,  # the source document
    0,  # the source page number
    clip=None,  # any subrectangle on source page
)

# if desired, more pages from other sources can be put on same target page
```

Comment: PyMuPDF did it for me. It keeps the plotter line from the original PDFs. The only weird thing is their scale. I had to calculate mm time 2.84 for some reason and could not find an explanation in the docs. But it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`cpdf in.pdf -stamp-on stamp.pdf -pos-left "x y" AND -stamp-on stamp2.pdf -pos-left "x2 y2" AND ..... -o out.pdf`

where in.pdf is a blank PDF of appropriate size, and x and y and x2 and y2 etc... are the coordinates required and ..... are parts of the command for the third, fourth etc. stamps.